# Redirect directly to the payment provider page

Tags: commerce, redirection, payment-gateways

I'm building a store with Drupal Commerce and creating my own off-site payment gateway.
On the review page, after selecting payment method, the user can click the button to pay and finish the order.
After that he's redirected to a page that tells him to wait to be redirected to the payment provider.

Is there a way to redirect the user to the payment provider without needing to go to this useless page ?

Thank you.

Comment: actually this is not a useless page, this page is in charge of building a from with hidden values which then submission of this form will cause redirecting to offsite payment along sending required information, in most cases a javascript will cause auto redirecting on page ready so it wont make much bother

Comment: I think this page is useless as for the customer it serve no purpose, the url redirect should be done in the back and only show the payment page to the customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a redirect link and doensn't need a page to have hidden values in a form, you can use the `self::REDIRECT_GET` instead of `self::REDIRECT_POST` in the `buildConfigurationForm` function of your payment method.